# luajit ffi string garbage-collected

Tags: lua, garbage-collection, ffi, luajit

I'm trying to find a way to prevent my strings from being collected by the gc. I'm using a small struct and it is populated using the snippet below. Ideally the table itself would move to an ffi struct but I not there yet (and I suspect that then all my structs will be gc-ed). I can go-around using static sizes but considering the amount of records and other similar structures I may move to ffi, this would be a large waste of RAM).

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
typedef struct {
    uint8_t     ctype;
    uint16_t    freq;
    char*       name;
    char*       icao;
} s_frq;
]]

local s_frq = ffi.typeof("s_frq")

[...]
local frq   = s_frq()
frq.ctype   = tonumber(fields[1])
frq.freq    = freq
frq.icao    = ffi.new("char[?]", #icao+1, icao)
frq.name    = ffi.new("char[?]", #name+1, name)
db_apt[icao].freqs[#db_apt[icao].freqs+1] = frq
```

I've read somewhere that:

> The latter. Pointers are not followed by the GC. Only references from
>   local variables, upvalues, Lua tables etc. are considered. This also
>   means you must not store the only reference to an object allocated
>   with ffi.new() as a pointer in a struct field.

but then I cannot figure out where I should store my pointers. Creating a lua table to store them side by side with my ffi struc would defeat the purpose of not using large lua tables (because the host application - X-Plane - will crash if receiving an alloc request bigger than 32MB).

Comment: You can manually manage the memory using `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: But then storing the pointers returned by malloc (so I can later free memory) would be equivalent to storing the return of ffi.new to prevent gc. Isn't it? (I'm talking about dozens of thousands of allocs).

Comment: If you manually manage memory, you don't have to keep the pointer in a place where LuaJIT's GC can find it, because the memory doesn't interact with the GC in any way (unless you use `ffi.gc` of course).

Comment: This sounds like it could make my day and if I understand well, I should myself do a malloc followed by a ffi.copy of my string, but then how do I know the parent struct is about to be destroyed so I can call free() on my char* before?

Comment: Attach a GC finalizer to the parent struct http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-04/msg00516.html

Comment: It works, thanks to both of you!